# Open InputStream as Reader

Tags: java, io, guava

Can I easily convert `InputStream` to `BufferedReader` using Guava?

I'm looking for something like:

```
InputStream inputStream = ...;
BufferedReader br = Streams.newBufferedReader(inputStream);
```

I can open files using the `Files.newReader(File file, Charset charset)`. That's cool and I want to do the same using the `InputStream`.

UPDATE:

Using `CharStreams.newReaderSupplier` seems to verbose for me. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in order to easily convert `InputStream` to `BufferedReader` using Guava I have to do something like that:

```
final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/etc/fstab");
Reader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(new InputSupplier<InputStream>(){
      public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
        return inputStream;
      }
    }, Charset.defaultCharset()).getInput());
```

Of course I can create helper do sth like:

```
return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

However I think that such helper should be offered by Guava IO. I can do such trick for File instance. Why cannot I for InputStream?

```
// Guava can do this
Reader r = Files.newReader(new File("foo"), charset);
// but cannot do this
Reader r = SomeGuavaUtil.newReader(inputStream, charset);
```

Correct me If I'm wrong but it seems to me like lack in the API.

Comment: I fully agree with you that this is something *very* common and it would be great if a common library like Guava would standardize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't anything quite like that in Guava. `CharStreams` is the general class for working with `Reader`s and `Writer`s and it has a method

```
InputSupplier<InputStreamReader> newReaderSupplier(
    InputSupplier<? extends InputStream> in, Charset charset)
```

which could be useful with any kind of supplier of `InputStream`s.

Obviously, you can just write `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, charset))` or wrap that in your own factory method as well.

**Edit:**

Yes, you wouldn't want to use the `InputSupplier` version when you already have an `InputStream`. It's sort of like how it's a bad idea to make an `Iterable` that can actually only work once, such as one that wraps an existing `Iterator` or `Enumeration` or some such. In general, using `InputSupplier` requires thinking about how you do I/O a little different, such as thinking of a `File` as something that can act as a supplier of `FileInputStream`s. I've used `InputSupplier`s that wrap whole requests to a server and return the response content as an `InputStream`, enabling me to use Guava utilities to copy that to a file, etc.

In any case, I'm not entirely sure why `CharStreams` doesn't have a method to create a `Reader` from an `InputStream` other than perhaps they didn't feel it was needed. You may want to file an issue requesting this.

Comment: +1 - The obvious solution is for the OP to add a 3 line helper method to his application!

Comment: I won't create my helper method - that's why I'm using Guava :)

Factory method newReaderSupplier is too verbose for me. I'll add explanation to the question above.

Comment: Certainly it's nice when Guava already has utilities to do what you want to do, but I think when it doesn't it's a good idea to create your own utilities to do that and replace them later if Guava adds such functionality.

Comment: Of course now I use my custom utilities when I need them. However I want to resign from them on the behalf of the Guava. I'll contact Google guys and ask them about helper method for converting InputStream to BufferedReader.